# How to get the url string from a text javascript

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink, href

How can I get the url string from a generated text.
For example I have generated a text

```
text =  "This is my sample text try http:\/\/sample.com\/23411";

convertedString = "This is my sample text try http://sample.com/23411";
```

I want to do this

```
var disp = "";

disp += "This is my sample text try";
disp += "<a href = 'http://sample.com/23411'>http://sample.com/23411</a>";
```

result

This is my sample text try http://sample.com/23411

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use a regex:

```
disp = text.replace(/(http:\/\/[^ ]+)/, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/49YFF/

Comment: Great! but how can I get the first text? The "This is my sample text try"? Sorry for just a simple question for you but I'm just new to Javascript.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan - Did you click on that link I posted?

Comment: I didn't see that before I refresh. Tnx got to try.